# CakePHP redirect .php to controller

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

My old website URL structure was something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?go=archives&data=lastweek
```

Today, I migrated to CakePHP, so that URL won't work. So I want to redirect it to this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/archives/find?data=lastweek
```

(I don't want to change query string to action parameter, for some reason, I should keep it as a query string.)

What should I do? (edit which `.htaccess` file? CakePHP has 3 files!)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear so it's to understand what you're trying to accomplish. Regarding the `.htaccess` files, if you want to use rewrite rules use the `.htaccess` file in the webroot directory.

Comment: @Hoff: I want to redirect a `.php` file to a CakePHP controller, with it's query string.. (because I get the query string in my controller action with `$this->request->query`)

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in your document root (preferably above any rules that may already be there), add these:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^go=archives&data=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /archives/find/?data=%1 [L,R=301]
```

This should 301 redirect `/index.php?go=archives&data=anything` to `/archives/find?data=anything`.